# In XGBoost, what's the difference between the 'objective' set in param and the obj parameter in the train function?

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost

When using the XGBoost package, we can set 'objective' in a param dict (for example:'objective': 'binary:logistic' ) and pass the dict to the train function.
In the meantime, there is an obj parameter in the train function. As far as I know, they are both objective functions. Then what's their difference? And if they are both set, which one will be in effect?

```
param = {'max_depth': 3, 'eta': 1, 'silent': 1, 'objective': 'binary:logistic'} 
bst = xgb.train(param, data_train, num_boost_round=n_round, obj=g_h, feval=error_rate)
```

where g_h is a self-defined objective function.

Strange enough, I find that If both 'objective': 'binary:logistic' and obj are set,  y_hat is

```
y_hat: [6.0993789e-06 9.8472750e-01 6.0993789e-06 ... 9.9993265e-01 4.4560062e-07
 9.9993265e-01]
```

If I skip 'objective': 'binary:logistic' and only obj in the train is set, y_hat is

```
y_hat: [-5.6174016  5.2989674 -5.6174016 ...  7.6525593 -6.4794073  6.7979865]
```

So obj in the train function does not override 'objective': 'binary:logistic'!

This is the code:

```
import xgboost as xgb

def g_h(y_hat, y):
    p = 1.0 / (1.0 + np.exp(-y_hat))
    g = p - y.get_label()
    h = p * (1.0-p)
    return g, h

# read in data
dtrain = xgb.DMatrix('demo/data/agaricus.txt.train')
dtest = xgb.DMatrix('demo/data/agaricus.txt.test')
# specify parameters via map
param = {'max_depth':3, 'eta':1, 'silent':1, 'objective':'binary:logistic' }
num_round = 7
bst = xgb.train(param, dtrain, num_round)
# make prediction
y_hat = bst.predict(dtest)
print(y_hat)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Originally the `objective` constructor argument only supported `string` values that defined a known objective such as the one in your example. The `obj` argument on the other hand expects a callable with the signature `objective(y_true, y_pred) -> grad, hess`

Nowadays though (at least in v0.7) both can just as well be a custom callable. For the user this means that you can use either way to define the objective, the one you pass to train will override the one defined in the constructor. My best guess is that both ways to define it still exists for backwards compatibility.

Comment: I did some experiments and I found out that obj in the train function does not override 'objective': 'binary:logistic'. How strange!

Comment: @Naomi, did you ever resolve this? I am running into the same behavior. XGBoost is version 1.6.1.